# Excel formula issue or macro issue

Tags: perl, vba, excel

IS there a way to add/subtract time from a start time and add/subtract time from an end time in one cell.

This is a time sheet. My boss would like to account for travel for our workers. IF you show up at 10:00 pm. he would want me to enter 10:00 pm, but the excel to show 9:30 pm.  And if you left at 11:00 pm, he would want me to enter 11:00 pm, but it show 11:30 pm.

I believe this is a macro, but I am not very educated when it comes to macros.

Answer (score 0):

Weird requirement but, assuming all appearance times (in a contiguous range) are to be reduced by 1/2hr and all departure times (in a different contiguous range) increased by 1/2 hr then it is possible without a macro.

Enter in an available cell:

```
=1/48
```

Copy that cell, select the arrival range, Paste Special, Operation Subtract, OK. Repeat for the departure range but with Operation Add.

The times may lose their formatting until re-applied. Where a cell fills with `#` (ie entered as within 1/2hr of midnight) add 1.

What may not suit is that the cells do not end up with the likes of `10:00:00 -00:30:00` displayed as `09:30:00` so there may be little to be gained over entering as 09:30 to begin with.

Comment: So just like you said, the cells fill with ##. Is there a way for it to actually be formatted with the time or are we just asking way too much?

Answer (score 0):

Are the travel times for all employees 30 minutes? This can be represented as "time(0,30,)"  in the formulas for your sums.  If each employee has different travel times then insert columns for travel times to the right of the start and end times and subtract them.

Insert columns labeled "adjusted start time" and "adjusted end time" and insert formulas like: "=B2-TIME(0,30,0)" where B2 is the start time and "=D2+TIME(0,30,0)" where D2 is the end time.  Omit the quotes.

I advise against having excel display numbers that are different from what you entered, it can become confusing if there is a question whether the travel time was added or not.

Comment: Did this fix your issue?  Please mark it as answered if it did